# Javascript to convert string to number?

Tags: javascript, numerical

```
var str = '0.25';
```

How to convert the above to `0.25?`

Comment: `parseInt` is blazing fast, but if you need decimals, you should go with `parseFloat`: https://jsbench.me/pokty2hchw/1

Comment: `'0.25'*1` is about 98% faster than `parseFloat()` https://jsbench.me/bflb5lcqpw/1

Comment: @Miro beware benchmarks against trivial single-value cases. The methods don't scale the same. Performing the same comparison on an array of 10 values at once, `parseFloat()` performs about 15% better than `''*1`: https://jsbench.me/c8ldyhrth3/1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve it:

Using the unary plus operator:

```
var n = +str;
```

The `Number` constructor:

```
var n = Number(str);
```

The `parseFloat` function:

```
var n = parseFloat(str);
```

Comment: Also, for integers (only), there's `~~str` and `str | 0`

Comment: Without knowing the implications and side effects of each of these, I'd opt for `Number(str)` as it's the most readable & interpretable code.

Answer (score 6):

For your case, just use:

```
var str = '0.25';
var num = +str;
```

There are some ways to convert string to number in javascript.

The **best** way:

```
var num = +str;
```

It's simple enough and work with both int and float
`num` will be `NaN` if the `str` cannot be parsed to a valid number

You also can:

```
var num = Number(str); //without new. work with both int and float
```

or

```
var num = parseInt(str,10); //for integer number
var num = parseFloat(str); //for float number
```

**DO NOT**:

```
var num = new Number(str); //num will be an object. (typeof num == 'object') will be true.
```

Use parseInt only for special case, for example

```
var str = "ff";
var num = parseInt(str,16); //255

var str = "0xff";
var num = parseInt(str); //255
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var num = Number(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var f = parseFloat(str);`