# numerical value of number input by user in a text field

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add up two numbers input by the user. To do that, I create two input fields, retrieve values from them , using .val(), in two separate variables and then add them. The problem is that the strings are added and not the numbers. For eg. 2 + 3 becomes 23 and not 5. please suggest what to do, except using type = number in the input boxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to convert string to number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130454/javascript-to-convert-string-to-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use parseInt(...)

Example:

```
var num = parseInt("2", 10) + parseInt("3", 10);
// num == 5
```

Comment: What if the user enters `2.5`? Even if you assume that only integers are allowed, please don't suggest `parseInt()` without using the second parameter to specify base 10 with `parseInt("2",10)`, because otherwise if the user enters a leading zero (e.g., "077") it may (depending on the browser) be treated as octal; if the user enters a leading "0x" it'll be treated as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert a string into a number:

```
var a = '2';
var b = '3';
var sum = parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10);
console.log(sum); /* 5 */
```

Keep in mind that `parseInt(str, rad)` will only work if `str` actually contains a number of base `rad`, so if you want to allow other bases you'll need to check them manually. Also note that you'll need to use `parseFloat` if you want more than integers.

Comment: What if `a` is `'2.5'`? What if a is `'0x77'` or `'077'` and you haven't specified the radix?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Fixed it, that was one of my earliest answers and I wasn't aware of the `parseInt` issues at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Either use parseInt (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or parseFloat (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to convert to a numerical value before adding.

PS: This is the simple answer. You might want to do some validation/stripping/trimming etc.

Answer (score 0):

Number() is the function you want "123a" returns NAN

parseInt() truncates trailing letters "123a" returns 123

```
<input type="text" id="txtFld" onblur="if(!Number(this.value)){alert('not a number');}" />
```

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at8ay/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier today. If you have an `input[type=number]` you can simply do `input.valueAsNumber`.

This will not work for every input-type though. It will work for `input[type=date]` but then you could do `input.valueAsDate`.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(input=>{
  input.addEventListener('input', e=>showInputValue(e.currentTarget))
  showInputValue(input)
})

function showInputValue(input) {
  input.nextSibling.textContent = ` // input.valueAsNumber -> ${input.valueAsNumber}`
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
label {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
span:first-child, input {
  width: 6rem;
  flex: 0 0 6rem;
}
span:last-child {
  flex: 1 0 16rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<label><span>text: </span><input type="text" value="123"><span></span></label>
<label><span>number: </span><input type="number" value="123"><span></span></label>
<label><span>range: </span><input type="range" value="123"><span></span></label>
<label><span>date: </span><input type="date" value="2022-07-06"><span></span></label>
```