# List all variable names in a object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object:

```
var sub = {
    0:  [""],
    21: ["Look, here, are three little stuff,","ready to sing for this crowd"],
    28: ["Listen up, 'cause here's our story","I'm gonna sing it very LOUUU..."],
    36: [""],
    45: ["VERY LOUUU..."],
    48: [""],
    61: ["When you're a younger stuff","and your stuff is very bare"],
    68: ["Feels like the sun will never come","when your stuff's not there"],
    74: ["So the three of us will fight the fight","there is nothing that we fear"],
    80: ["We'll have to figure out what we'll do next","till our stuff is here!"],
    87: ["We are the guys","on a quest to find out who we are"],
    94: ["And we will never stop the journey","not until we have our stuff"],
    101:[""],
    106:["(stuff...)"],
}
//I like stuff.
```

And I would like to get all of the variable names into an array, like so:

```
variables == [0, 21, 28, 36, 45, 48, 61, 68, 74, 80, 87, 94, 101, 106, 109];
```

Is there a built in function for this, or is it possible to iterate over JSON object variables?

Comment: This is a JavaScript object, not a JSON object! Please read [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Objects have *properties*, not variables. What you are looking for is the *names* of the properties.

Comment: Following the solution in the linked question will give you an array of strings though. If you want to convert them to numbers, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130454/javascript-to-convert-string-to-number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most browsers have this method built right into the Object prototype.

You can use

```
var variables = Object.keys(sub); //returns an array with all the object keys
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome! I like this solution better since it doesn't require `for` loops.

Comment: This will return an array of string though

Comment: Thanks this helped me! really good awsner instead of using loops

Answer (score 1):

```
var variables = [];
for (var i in sub) {
 if (sub.hasOwnProperty(i)){
  variables.push(+i);
 }
}
```

This is a manual solution. I recommend you using Underscore.js for problems like this. There is a good `_.keys` method in Underscore.

Comment: I'd drop a `.hasOwnProperty` here too.

Comment: Just be aware this will 1) return `["94", "21", "36", ..]` due to the `[ToString]` of *property* names; and 2) the order is *not* guaranteed.

Comment: @pst Is there a way to create the new array in a way that the order is precise?

Comment: @DJDavid98: No, object properties have no specific order. It's like a hash map.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess I can use a `.sort()` on it, so it will be all good.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Of course, if the property names are sortable, like in your example, then yes.

Comment: @Kos and @ pst you are both right. Updated!